# Convert html input type number to actual number from html

Tags: python, flask

I have a html form which I am using a threshold for a python function.
I managed to get the data as expected, but when I try to use the input for number it returns a string instead a float/number. I have been researching when I could use JS to do the conversion, still nothing really concrete found.

```
<form method="Post", id="myform">
    <input type="number" id="threshold" name="threshold" min=".1" max="100">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

app.route("/dp", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report():
    v = request.form.get("threshold")

    if request.method=='POST':
        //code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask's form parser returns all data in string format regardless of how the input field itself is defined in your HTML; cast it to the datatype you need on the back-end in your Flask route:

```
@app.route("/dp", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report():
    v = float(request.form.get("threshold"))

    if request.method=='POST':
        //code
```

See [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int) for further discussion on casting a string to `int` and `float` datatypes.

Comment: I had done that inside the python script, but apparently it is return a NoneType value. It was a good suggestion though.

Comment: I have to add float(v.replace(',','.')) and it did work.